# C# Pass multiple parameters into XML using Queue

Tags: c#, xml, list, for-loop, parameters

I have a webservice that obtains data from Oracle CRM OnDemand. I want to create another WS that takes the fields for a given customer record and passes those fields as parameters into an XML writer which then creates the XML to be passed to another webservice (being developed by another team).

I can create the XML fine and pass the parameters. However, I am only testing 3-4 fields and passing them. I will need way more than 4 parameters to be passed, and I know this is pretty poor programming to create a function that takes 3+ parameters. (EDIT) I have created a queue that takes in the parameters from the page, and I pass just the queue. I want to dequeue the data field followed by a string of what I want to pass into the XML page.

This is what I have right now.

```
...for (int intIndx = 0; intIndx < intCount; intIndx++)
                    {
                        //Create queue to store all the data obtained from a given Account
                        Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>();
                        //Easier to reference 
                        var acctName=  objAcctQryOut.ListOfAccount[intIndx].AccountName;
                        var acctWebsite = objAcctQryOut.ListOfAccount[intIndx].WebSite;
                        q.Enqueue(acctName);                            
                        addyInsert.CountryCode = objAcctQryOut.ListOfAccount[intIndx].PrimaryBillToCountry;
                        q.Enqueue(addyInsert.CountryCode);
                        addyInsert.Line1 = objAcctQryOut.ListOfAccount[intIndx].PrimaryBillToStreetAddress;
                        q.Enqueue(addyInsert.Line1);
                        addyInsert.Line2 = accountInfo.PrimaryBillToStreetAddress2;
                        q.Enqueue(addyInsert.Line2);
                        addyInsert.Line3 = accountInfo.PrimaryBillToStreetAddress3;
                        q.Enqueue(addyInsert.Line3);
                        addyInsert.City = objAcctQryOut.ListOfAccount[intIndx].PrimaryBillToCity;
                        q.Enqueue(addyInsert.City);
                        addyInsert.CountyCodeVertex = accountInfo.PrimaryBillToCounty;
                        q.Enqueue(addyInsert.CountyCodeVertex);
                        addyInsert.StateProvinceCodeVertex = accountInfo.PrimaryBillToState;
                        q.Enqueue(addyInsert.StateProvinceCodeVertex);even know? 
                        custResponse.CustomerNumber = accountInfo.FuriganaName;
                        q.Enqueue(custResponse.CustomerNumber);
                        custInput.BillingCurrency = accountInfo.CurrencyCode;
                        q.Enqueue(custInput.BillingCurrency);
                        custInput.Email = accountInfo.CustomText1;
                        q.Enqueue(custInput.Email);
                        custInput.TravelPortCustomerTypeCode = accountInfo.AccountType;
                        q.Enqueue(custInput.TravelPortCustomerTypeCode);
                        var count = q.Count;

                        var xml = new XML();
                        xml.sendAccountInfoXML(q);
                        //xml.sendAccountInfoXML(acctName, addyInsert.CountryCode, addyInsert.Line1, addyInsert.Line2, addyInsert.Line3, acctWebsite);

                    }

private void createXML(Queue<string> q)
        {
            string saveLoc = @"C:\Users\XML Test\test{0}.xml";
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(saveLoc, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.Indentation = 2;
            writer.WriteStartElement("HEADER");
            createNode(q, writer);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Close();
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
private void createNode(Queue<string> q, XmlWriter writer)
        {
            Queue<string> x = new Queue<string>();
            x.Enqueue("ACCOUNTNAME");
            x.Enqueue("BILLINGCOUNTRY");
            x.Enqueue("BILLINGLINE1");
            x.Enqueue("BILLINGLINE2");
            x.Enqueue("BILLINGLINE3");
            x.Enqueue("BILLINGCITY");
            x.Enqueue("BILLINGCOUNTY");
            x.Enqueue("BILLINGSTATE");
            x.Enqueue("CUSTOMERNUMBER");
            x.Enqueue("BILLINGCURRENCY");
            x.Enqueue("CUSTOMEREMAIL");
            x.Enqueue("CUSTOMERTYPE");
            //x.Enqueue("CUSTOMURL");
            writer.WriteStartElement("ACCOUNTINFO");
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Count; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement(x.Dequeue());
                for (int j = 0; j < q.Count; j++)
                {
                    writer.WriteString(q.Dequeue());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

However, I feel that the nested loops are not properly functioning. Would you mind trying to guide me through it and point out where I'm messing up? Thank you.

Comment: You could just accept a `IDictionary` or `ILookup` and put whatever's in there in the XML...

Comment: `ILookup` is for mapping keys to enumerations, not individual values. `IDictionary` might be appropriate, but there are too many different options here to keep this question from being too broad. As far as creating the XML goes, you would probably find it easier to use `XmlDocument` or `XDocument`, both of which provide a full "document object model" to generate the XML, rather than a linear writer-based approach. For that matter, it's _possible_ XML serialization would be the most convenient approach. But the question isn't specific enough to address in a non-broad way.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What other details are you needing? I came up with the idea of storing each CRM field as an item in a queue, then passing the queue to a method that writes out each item from the queue into an XML file.

Comment: A dictionary is better than a queue, as it's not order-dependent. As for "what other details", the issue here isn't so much the lack of details (though there is that), it's that there's not a _specific_ question here. You're really just asking for broad design advice, in a scenario that is fundamentally working fine for you now. Your question is probably better suited to the programmer.stackexchange.com site than here (StackOverflow is more for _fixing_ code or otherwise helping others get past parts of their program that aren't working).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have a more specific question now. Hopefully this hasn't been too frustrating.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on how and why to provide a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example that clearly illustrates your scenario, as well as what it means to do so.